# Execute Stored Procedure in another Stored Procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to understand how do you call a stored procedure in another stored procedure in Oracle.

For example: In SQL Server stored procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P2
.
.
.
DECLARE v_Id INT

EXEC P1 v_Name, v_Id OUTPUT
```

Both `v_Name` and `v_Id` is available in procedure P1.

How do you call the same in Oracle

Answer (score 4):

Something like this is what you're after

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p2
AS
  -- Do not use the `DECLARE` keyword
  -- Variables must be defined at the top of the block
  v_id pls_integer; 
BEGIN
  <<do stuff>>

  -- Just call the procedure.  No need for `EXEC`.  
  --  There is also no need to indicate that a parameter is an OUT parameter in the call
  p1( v_name, v_id );
END;
```

A few things to be aware of

- Variables are defined at the top of the block (between the `AS` and the `BEGIN`) rather than being defined inline.  You can create nested PL/SQL blocks within your procedure where you declare variables whose scope is just that nested block rather than the procedure but I'm ignoring that possibility here.
- In PL/SQL, you don't need any keyword to indicate a procedure call.  Just call it.
- You don't need to indicate that a parameter is an `OUT` parameter (or `IN OUT`).  That is defined by the procedure you're calling.